# Logging / Log4J to database

Tags: grails, log4j

In my Grails application, I run some batch processes asynchronously, and would like the process to log various status messages so that the administrator later can examine them.

I thought of using log4j JDBC appender as the simplest solution, but from what I can tell it doesn't use DataSource.  Has anybody gotten it to work or wrote their own Grails DB Appender?

Did anybody have a similar requirement, and how did you implement it?

I can create a notion of Job, which hasMany LoggingMessages, but thought perhaps there is a standard way or a plugin that does this.

P.S. There was a somewhat related discussion a few weeks ago, but that one was about a different aspect than what I need. 
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Async-Event-that-publishes-progress-td2303653.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone seems to have written a version of the log4j JDBC appender that does use a datasource and adds some other nice features.  Have a look at this [blog entry](http://www.boky.cc/2010/02/03/jdbcappender-for-log4j/) by the author.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider stand alone log server, I'd recommend [this tool](http://www.logfaces.com). It would accept log data over sockets and persist them. Works with many database brands too. Very simple to set up. It's not a free tool though...